# Django problem: problem with choice fields

Tags: django, forms, model, django-queryset

I seem to have problem in Django when looking for a field which has a choice parameter. I do not get the field name but instead I get the number for some odd reason.

My `forms.py`:

```
from django import forms

CONTRACT_TYPE_CHOICES = (
                 (1, 'Annual'),
                 (2, 'Ad-hoc'),
                 )

CONTRACT_STATUS_CHOICES = (
  (1, 'Active'),
  (2, 'In-Active'),
  )

class ContractForm(forms.ModelForm):
  contract_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CONTRACT_TYPE_CHOICES) 
  contract_status = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CONTRACT_STATUS_CHOICES) 

  class Meta:
    model = Contract
```

In my template. I have the following

```
{% for contracts in contracts_list %}
  {{contracts.client_contract_number}}<br/>
  {{contracts.contract_type}}<br/>
  {{contracts.contract_status}}<br/>
{% endfor %}
```

They all return a value. But `contact_type` and `contract_status` returns numbers. I do not to make it return numbers but the names. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Model fields that take a choices kwarg automagically get a `get_FIELD_NAME_display` method. So for example, you could should put this in your template:

```
{{ contracts.get_contract_type_display }}
{{ contracts.get_contract_status_display }}
```

See the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display).

Good luck,
Justin